# LiveAgentSession objects during agent session

Tags: liveagent

According to the docs, there is a standard object called LiveAgentSession.  The doc says "This object is automatically created for each Live Agent session and stores information about the session.".  I am trying to see which live agent sessions are currently up, and I thoought I could use this object to get me that info.  But this only seems to have sessions which have completed, not existing sessions.  Is there a way to see the existing sessions?

Answer (score 1):

You can access LiveAgent events through the API. There's a call that returns current session data:  ChasitorSessionData.

More information [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages_responses_overview.htm)